# XMLHttpRequest Cross origin requests In Dart with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, dartium

I'm loading a json file relatively using dart's html library's HttpRequest class. In the Dart editor it's working fine. Using the dart plugin for intelliJ with JetBrains chrome extension I receive...

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/project/web/path/to/my/file.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.  :0
Exception: Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
Stack Trace: #0      HttpRequest.send (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-trunk/build/src/build/Release/obj/global_intermediate/webkit/bindings/dart/dart/html/HttpRequest.dart:33:3)
```

I'm passing a relative url, when inspecting the URL I see its:
"path/to/my/file.json"

Here's the bare bones test.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main(){
  Loader loader = new Loader();
  loader.load("someFile.json");
}

class Loader {
  load(String url) {
    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it works in one context and not another, but basically cannot just go `GET` a file if you are not using `http`. See these for details on why this is the case. I've never used IntelliJ, so I cannot speak to the specifics of that context, unfortunately.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-but-im-loading-a-co
```

Comment: Hey, I added a bare bones example. Does it look okay to you?

Comment: I went with your second link. --disable-web-security

Comment: Shailen, IntelliJ loads Dartium with files from the filesystem not from a localhost web server like DartEditor does.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, financeCoding.