# Error: Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP with D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, xmlhttprequest, sunburst-diagram

I was trying to generate sunburst chart from the example provided [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423)

What I did is just copy the entire JSON in my local and then the index.html

I didn't do any changes to any of the files.

When I tried to run the html file I'm getting these errors

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/VK/Documents/D3%20charts/sunburst/flare.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. d3.v3.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined d3.v3.min.js:2
Uncaught NetworkError: A network error occurred. d3.v3.min.js:1
```

found a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain) but I don't want to load it form the webserver

Can any one help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Try using Firefox as I think it's more relaxed towards cross browser requests than some other browsers. Otherwise, you might want to look into pythons simple server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP but it's not cross-domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain)

Comment: @Quentin the solution provided there was to use webserver. I don't want to use a webserver. moreover there are other 2 issue in D3.v3.min.js.

Comment: @user1614080 In firefox it is working, But it needs to work on all the browsers right. do you know any way to do so

Comment: @strikers You'll have to run it from a webserver if you want it to work on all browsers. The other errors you're seeing are a result of it not being able to load the file.

Comment: If you have python installed, then go the the folder where you have downloaded the files, do `python -mSimpleHTTPServer`, and point your browser to `http://localhost:8000/index.html`. Similar solutions exist using node, nginx, ruby, apache, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers don't support loading files through file:// so the best you can do is load your frontend through a web server.

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.