# Trying to disable Chrome same origin policy

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to follow a melonJS tutorial. It says I should disable cross-origin request using one of two methods:

--disable-web-security

**--allow-file-access-from-files****

I've tried both of these in my command prompt as such:

```
C:\Users\danniu>C:\Users\danniu\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.e
xe --allow-file-access-from-files

C:\Users\danniu>C:\Users\danniu\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.e
xe --disable-web-security
```

When I try to run the game in Chrome I'm still getting this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/danniu/Desktop/JavaScript/melonJS/data/map/area01.tmx. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use both arguments. This is how I run it on my mac.

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security -–allow-file-access-from-files
```

This is how it should be for windows:

```
"C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" –allow-file-access-from-files -disable-web-security
```

Comment: so it would look like this? `C:\Users\danniu>C:\Users\danniu\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.e
xe --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files` , then I can just open my game in that new browser window?

Comment: You might also need to add the --args parameter

Comment: Check out edit. For windows you actually just need to use one dash

Comment: Okay hmm. Still not working. Any way to verify within the new browser window that I've disabled those?

Comment: well one way is you're not getting the cross origin error. But as soon as you open the browser, a yellow bar should appear at the top saying you're in an unsecure mode. Also, make sure to kill all chrome tasks before running that flag. Otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 3):

To disable chrome web security on mac use this command on terminal

$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security

if $ open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security -–allow-file-access-from-files 
dosen't help

Answer (score 0):

You should request through a HTTP protocol

Here's an answer quite simple to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118676/1585438

Answer (score 0):

The anti-SOP paramters:

`--disable-web-security -–allow-file-access-from-files`

To make the parameters  effective, there must not be another instance of chrome running. If you have **chrome running already** and start a new instance with the anti-SOP parameters, it will have no effect.

When you close chrome, make sure that all instances are closed. This includes **instances without GUI** as well (task manager is your friend)!