# paste image with clipboard API - CKEditor

Tags: javascript, file-upload, ckeditor, copy-paste, clipboard.js

i saw this [link question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c/6338207#6338207), i'm trying to do the purpose of this link, but i'm getting this error below when i paste text or an image

[image]

i'm using the CKeditor and am configuring the paste event in config.js of CKeditor, the code is:

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2016, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.height = '420px';

};

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (event) {
    event.editor.on('paste', function (event) {
      // use event.originalEvent.clipboard for newer chrome versions
      var items = (event.clipboardData  || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // will give you the mime types
      // find pasted image among pasted items
      var blob = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
          blob = items[i].getAsFile();
        }
      }
      // load image if there is a pasted image
      if (blob !== null) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.result); // data url!
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      }
    });
});
```

I need to include any file of clipboard API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` in `editor.on('paste', function (event)...` is not an original event.

From [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste), you can get that is [CKEDITOR.eventInfo](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.eventInfo) object.

So, from docs, the data can be accessed by `event.data.dataValue` without using clipboard API.

You can get more information form [Clipboard Integration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_clipboard).

**UPDATED**

Try this to get data.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (event) {
    event.editor.on('paste', function (pasteEvent) {
      var items = pasteEvent.data.dataValue;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
    });
});
```

Comment: i didn't understand the documentation, i change a little more the code, but it didn't make difference on funcionality @fumi_hwh

Comment: just use `event.data.dataValue` to get data from paste event

Comment: now the error change, it are showing: "Not allowed to load local resource:", are pasting the image with physical source @fumi_hwh

Comment: It is actually another question. Maybe you could find the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901523/file-url-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-the-internet-browser)

Comment: ok, i'm curious because ckeditor are putting a base64 "version" of the same after the physical source, do you know why it occurs?

Comment: oh, i found it, it is because i have the plugin 'pastebase64', tks for help. :)

Comment: i'm testing here, and when i take a print of my screen the text returned in data.dataValue is empty, do you know how i can paste it too?