# Display pages source in iframe?

Tags: iframe

This might be one of the more daft questions to ask,

but since

```
<iframe src="view-source:https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/Daymusic.html" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
```

doesn't work:

Is it possible to display **a page's source** inside an iframe?
(Or any other way really ??)

CLARIFICATION:
I know about the browsers built in "view source" function.
I want the page source being rendered *without* user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript to fetch the page in question and escape the html.

As an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mw0tz5sd/) try using JQuery:

```
$.get('https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/Daymusic.html', function(data) { 
            var x = document.createElement("pre");
            x.id = "test"
            $("body").append(x); 
            $("#test").text(data);
    });
```

Or another example with [iframe](https://codepen.io/roeften/pen/KKyydjL)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can you show me how to make your example work with an simple iframe ? (Jsfiddle is not my cup of tea. Codepen is far more transparent ..)

Comment: @Rye I have added an example on Codepen, the idea is the same, escape the html and add it to an element. I do not think you can make an iframe load the source and not render it without a solution like this.

Comment: K. Thats good enough. Meanwhile I also found this. Options are always good. Thanks ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945094/add-option-to-view-source-of-current-html-page