# Load CSS files with an array

Tags: php, css, arrays

I want to load CSS files with an array and a foreach loop,

```
<?php
    define("DS",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    define("APP_PATH",__DIR__);
    define('CSS_PATH',APP_PATH.DS."assets".DS.'css'.DS);
     $css_files = array('font-awesome.min.css','bootstrap.min.css','normalize.min.css'
                          ,'owl.carousel.min.css','main.css');
        foreach($css_files as $css){?>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH.$css?>"/>
          <?php } ?>
```

but the browser prevents loading with an array:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/programs/Xampp/htdocs/LOCA_PDO/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css

    Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/programs/Xampp/htdocs/LOCA_PDO/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

    Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/programs/Xampp/htdocs/LOCA_PDO/assets/css/normalize.min.css

    localhost/:44 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/programs/Xampp/htdocs/LOCA_PDO/assets/css/main.css
```

[image: CSS arrays]

Comment: Have a look at the HTML source code, is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: Use some other browser than chrome, it can be a browser security limitation. Plus, you might find a solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901523/file-url-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-the-internet-browser)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware of course

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I update question

Comment: That's PHP source code, not HTML source code. You can view the HTML source code in your browser, often by right clicking on the page and select 'View Page Source' from the local menu.

Comment: "browser prevent loading with array" — Look at the **error message**. It tells you why it isn't loading the files and it has nothing to do with the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/CSS/Style.css" type="text/css" />
```

You need to change

```
define('CSS_PATH',APP_PATH.DS."assets".DS.'css'.DS);
```

to

```
define('CSS_PATH',DS."assets".DS.'css'.DS);
```

This is assuming `LOCA_PDO` is the root of your website

Comment: but css files i put into `assets/css`

Comment: And thats what I have defined as CSS_PATH. Try and let me know.