# Summernote it may have been moved or deleted (can't paste video)

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

Can't paste video in **summernote js**[image]

Here's my **summernote** configuration

```
$('.summernote-block').summernote({
  height: 250, 
  focus: true,

  toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['insert', ['link', 'picture','videoAttributes','media', 'video', 'table', 'hr']],
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline','style']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['style', 'ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']],
    ['view', ['fullscreen']]

  ],
  popover: {
    airMode: true,
    image: [
      ['imagesize', ['imageSize100', 'imageSize50', 'imageSize25']],
      ['float', ['floatLeft', 'floatRight', 'floatNone']],
      ['remove', ['removeMedia']]
    ],
    video: [
      ['providers', ['YouTube', 'Vimeo', 'Vine', 'Instagram', 'DailyMotion', 'Youku']]
    ],
    link: [
      ['link', ['linkDialogShow', 'unlink']]
    ],
    air: [
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'paragraph']],
      ['table', ['table']],
      ['insert', ['link', 'picture','video']]
    ]

  }
});
```

WHat I include in head tag of html file.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../assets/css/now-ui-dashboard.css?v=1.1.0" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
  <!-- <link href="../assets/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
  <link href="../assets/js/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also in the bottom before the closing body

```
 <script src="../assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  // <script src="../assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- include summernote css/js -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
  <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
  <!-- Chart JS -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js"></script>
  <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
  <!-- Control Center for Now Ui Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
  <script src="../assets/js/now-ui-dashboard.min.js?v=1.1.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Now Ui Dashboard DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
  <script src="../assets/demo/demo.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Javascript method's body can be found in assets/js/demos.js
      demo.initGoogleMaps();
    });
  </script>
```

WHat I tried to do.

1.I try to replace **summernote** include `script` tag with other script's  except `bootstrap` `popper` or `jQuery` 
2.T try to use simple configuration of summernote I remove all configuration and paste this code below

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#summernote').summernote();
 });
```

3.I try to use some of video plugins in summernote.

Also in **codepen** I saw many example's which paste video without any configuration and the including same file's like in my situation and it work's perfectly.

**Please heeeelp.**

Comment: do you need past video url?

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal yup .I need click tag video add url like in here https://codepen.io/asiffermann/pen/EKvMMm  .

Comment: While attempting to insert the video, do you see any errors in the console (press F12 to open devtools)?
Do you have any adblock software that might be interfering or a proxy that blocks youtube?

Comment: @Tom Thank you for helping.Yup I found an error in console __Not allowed to load local resource: (after coming my youtube url)__ also I remove adblock but this don't help.

Comment: @Spectr I guess you are running this locally, are you able to move your code to a public web server to test? Here are some posts related to the error you see, maybe they'll help...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901523/file-url-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-the-internet-browser

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource

Comment: @Tom yup exactly I run it using apache and everything worked.Write your'e answer I'll accept it and will give you bounty :)

Comment: moved my comments to an answer so you can accept, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While attempting to insert the video, do you see any errors in the console (press F12 to open devtools)? Do you have any adblock software that might be interfering or a proxy that blocks youtube?

I guess you are running this locally, are you able to move your code to a public web server to test? Here are some posts related to the error you see, maybe they'll help...

[File URL "Not allowed to load local resource" in the Internet Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901523/file-url-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-the-internet-browser)

[Cannot open local file - Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

Comment: I will give a bounty to your'e answer after 2 hour's here have a limit.