# Use window.open to open a URL stored in a variable

Tags: javascript

First, I am getting the URL of the website currently open and storing that value inside a variable. Then I declare a new variable which adds "view-source:" + the variable with the URL I had previously declared. This prints out the address to the source code of said website.

I want to be able to use window.open so that the new value stored in the second variable is used as the URL inside the parameters. Here is my code:

```
let page = window.location.href;
let sourcecode = "view-source:" + page;

window.open(sourcecode);
```

How can I achieve this?
Alternatively, is there a way to open the source code directly through JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: The problem isn't with opening the url. It is just "view-source" was never meant for javascript to use. It is counted as a local resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening windows (or having `<a href`s) which start with `view-source:` is forbidden in major browsers, unfortunately: it's a [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901523/file-url-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-the-internet-browser) [issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/47#Security).

From a loaded page, there's no *generic* way to identify the view-source content, unfortunately. However, in many situations, you can fetch the page *again*, and examine the response text. For example, if the URL you're on is https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/, you could do:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    console.log(responseText);
  });
```

*If* nothing in the HTML changes the DOM before the final end tag, then you can reliably check the `innerHTML` in a script tag that runs just before the end of parsing, for example:

```js
console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

But this will not work if any `<script>`s change the DOM before DOMContentLoaded (and many do).

Comment: Would it be possible to look for a specific term or string of text in the console after the data is logged to it?

Comment: Sure, it's probably possible, though the actual code would depend on the what exactly the requirements are, of course

Comment: Say the data that was just logged contains the word "correct". I would like the script to look for that word and then grab the whole line of text to be displayed in an alert for the user.

Ex: The answer is correct!

The script would look for the word "correct" and then use alert() to display the whole line "The answer is correct!"

Comment: Split the response by lines, then use `.find` to find a line that includes the word you're looking for: `lines.find(line => line.includes('correct'))`

Comment: Your answer ended up being way better than opening a `view-source:` window, lol, thx