# php server unable to recieve the json variable from angularjs using $.http().post request

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ajax

Iam doing a post request to a php script form my AngularJS for mobile app.
when iam using  this code form action="url" method="post" in html.its working fine.
but when iam using ajax url request in angularjs , php server is not receiving the values.Then how can i achieve that

mycode:

var data: { jwt: 's21@s.com' }

```
    var req={
      method : 'POST',
    url: 'http:url//'
    }

       $http(req).success(function(data){

    alert(JSON.stringify(data));

       }).error(function(data) {
        alert("failure");

    alert(JSON.stringify(data));


       });


 }
```

myphp code:

$id = $_POST["jwt"];

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the JS console?  Angular is not like PHP. It's quite a bit more verbose at what's going on.  At first guess you might be having some problems with XHR but check that JS console...

Comment: error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: So you have a classic cross-domain error.  You can't run an XHR request from two pages residing on the same machine.   Try uploading the code to a server, or you can disable XHR permissions in chrome which has been covered numerous times on stack, including here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026984/trying-to-disable-chrome-same-origin-policy  Also, as Ohgodwhy suggests below, you aren't quite using $http.post correctly.  But one error at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this is th prefect solution. i got the answer

var app=angulamodule("myapp",[])
.config(function ($httpProvider){
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
        if (data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        return serialize(data);
    };  
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
})


var serialize = function(obj, prefix) {
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
      str.push(typeof v == "object" ?
        serialize(v, k) :
        encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
};
```

var req={
      method : 'POST',
    url: 'http:url//'
    }

```
   $http(req).success(function(data){

alert(JSON.stringify(data));

   }).error(function(data) {
    alert("failure");

alert(JSON.stringify(data));


   });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is the incorrect way to use `$http.post`. It's just a wrapper for `$http({})`. What you actually want is either to just use `$http({})` or use `$http.post()` accordingly:

```
$http.post(
    req.url,
    //your data
).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```