# How to suppress warning in chrome when using unsupported command-line flags?

Tags: google-chrome, same-origin-policy

I am working on a local app that does a few "bad things" mainly using files from a local file system and fetching resources from over site as well.  This has led to a violation of the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in Chrome.  I am well aware of the security issues with this but need to do it.

In looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026984/trying-to-disable-chrome-same-origin-policy) and several others on the internet, many suggest starting Chrome with a variety of command line flags mainly `--disable-web-security`

The issue with this is that Chrome then starts with the warning:

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer

Right below the address bar.

This is for an installation so I obviously can not have this popping up every time I start the app.  Is there a way to suppress this?

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/O4WpwWvGz4A) makes it seem like that would be impossible but man, that would be annoying.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by using this Chrome extension: [Allow-Controll-Allow Origin: *](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQt5b89qXOAhVIvhQKHWUcBNcQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fallow-control-allow-origi%2Fnlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi&usg=AFQjCNHbySktM7wLJjxA63D4xj6dr3jkTw&sig2=0dz20kVYsf-FjTgyAQcJsg).

[image]

Note: Sometimes you'll see that extension isn't working; just disable and enable "Enable cross-origin resource sharing" and it will work again.