# How can I display and download an image which is located outside of the static folder?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-admin

I'm setting up a script and I want to display an image which is located outside of my static folder. My project is designed like this:

```
___folder
  |__ image.png
  |__ text.txt
___web
  |__static
    |__ css
    |__ js
  |__ app.py
```

At the moment, I just run my script app.py. I have managed to create a hyperlink to download my image from another folder using the file protocol with this:

```html
<a href="file://///{{ image_path }}">Download </a><br>
```

This way works but I'm forced to right click on the hyperlink and paste it in a new window in order to download it. I'm looking for a way to just left click on it.

After that, I've tried to display this same image with:

```html
<img src="file://///{{ image_path }}" style="width:100%;" alt="Image not found">
```

but it actually doesn't work even if the path works for the previous part.

I've obtained some errors, when I've inspected the page as:

```html
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

### **UPDATE 1**

Is there a way to solve my issue by using mimetype here?

---

Any help or direction is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask why you've used `/////` rather than `//`?

Comment: I think that I just need to write `///` instead of `/////` [topic where I found some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp
Simply add the `download` attribute to your `<a>` tag, e.g.,

```
<a href="file://///{{ image_path }}" download="filename.png">
```

The `="filename.png"` is optional, you can just have `download` with no paramaters.

Comment: With your method I'm still forced to paste the link in another page, by clicking on the hyperlink nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security exception built into Chrome. In the past you could override  settings in Chrome [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027002/692942).
Check other topic in Stack, I can link dozens where you can find by yourself some help. You could use an intermediary page that serves the network based files for example.

You can find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Is there a way exists to pass through this?