# Loading KML file on Google map using Geoxml3

Tags: google-maps, geoxml3

My HTML is as under

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Complex</title>


<style>
   html{height:100%;}
   body{height:100%;margin:0px;font-family: Helvetica,Arial;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {        
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.397, -100.644),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    singleInfoWindow: true,
    afterParse: useTheData
     });
     geoXml.parse('google_earth_tutorial_files.kml');
    }
   );

   function useTheData(doc) {
    // Geodata handling goes here, using JSON properties of the doc object
    for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].markers.length; i++) {
        // console.log(doc[0].markers[i].title);
        jQuery('#map_text').append(doc[0].markers[i].title + ', ');
    }
  };
</script>

</head>
<body >
 <form id="form1">

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>

    <div id="map_text"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that on my machine I get an error on developer tools

```
GET google_earth_tutorial_files.kml  geoxml3.js:1169
geoXML3.fetchXML geoxml3.js:1169
fetchDoc geoxml3.js:160
parse geoxml3.js:155
(anonymous function) testmypage2.html:35
n jquery.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

Line 35 in my html is geoXml.parse('google_earth_tutorial_files.kml');

I don't know why this is happening. Please help.
I can see the map but no KML layer gets loaded

My KML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Placemark>
   <name>Manfred Mustermann</name>
   <description>Manfred Mustermann</description>
   <Point>
      <coordinates>7.0964850607874,51.781641735074,0</coordinates>
   </Point>
   <address>Musterstr 29 Aachen, 52070 Nordrhein-Westfalen</address>
   <styleUrl>#0</styleUrl>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Comment: Looks like a problem in your "useTheData" function (it is a jquery error, and that is the only place I see that used). What does the KML look like? Is there a publicly accessible version somewhere?

Comment: I have posted the KML in the question.

I have also removed the code you have asked me to. I now get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  in useTheData in markers.length

Comment: My kml is not public. It sits on my machine

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_SO_geoxml3_jqueryError.html)

Comment: Yes I can see. Obviously I am doing something wrong. Question - Do I run the HTML and KML file from a folder on my machine or does it have to be a webserver?
If it has to be a webserver then does it make a difference if my web application is not public?

Comment: The KML has to be public link

Comment: Not necessarily.  The third party parser geoxml3 only requires that the KML be in the same domain, so a relative reference to a file on your local computer will work (if allowed by the security policy of the browser you are running).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [This answer about loading local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain) might help (if you are using Chrome)
- [possible duplicate (about loading local files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-but-im-loading-a-co)
- [this google search](https://www.google.com/?q=Cross+origin+requests+are+only+supported+for+HTTP.&o=15527&l=dis&prt=NIS&chn=retail&geo=US&ver=19&gct=sb&qsrc=2869#q=Cross+origin+requests+are+only+supported+for+HTTP.) might help.

if you can run a local web server, it doesn't matter to geoxml3 if your application is public, but you need to read the [Terms of Service for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos)

Comment: The file and the html both are in localhost/<webname> directory

Comment: I got it working with parseKmlString since it could not find my file - Thanks