# Angularjs ng-view not showing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angularjs from Tuts+ Easier JavaScript Apps with AngularJS tutorial. Now I am at the part where they discussed Routing Primer using ng-view. I am trying to show the list page contents in ng-view of index page. For some reason nothing is shown when I load index.html. I found from searching that From angular 1.2.0, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. I have to load it separately and declare the dependency. But still I can't show anything from my list page.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
  <title>Angular App</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

list.html

```
<h3>List</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <a href="#">{{contact.name}}</a>: {{contact.number}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'list.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        });
    });

    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.contacts = [
            { name: 'Shuvro', number: '1234' },
            { name: 'Ashif', number: '4321' },
            { name: 'Anik', number: '2314' }
        ];
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `ng-controller` from the div like this:

```
<body>
<div >
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

To void "miss-routings" add the `otherwise` to the main configuration like:   `otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});`

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'list.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

**[Online Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QVH9ZadvJvurHhQdqVyS?p=preview)**

Comment: I removed the ng-controller and added otherwise to routeprovider as you said, but still nothing shown.

Comment: the url showing in my browser is 'file:///C:/Users/Shuvro/Desktop/AngularApp/index.html#/' . If that helps to find anything I'm missing.

Comment: @Shuvro it works on my end [**Online Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QVH9ZadvJvurHhQdqVyS?p=preview)

Comment: ok its working. It's turned out to be a google chrome issue. It's working fine in my firefox. and to solve the google chrome problem I followed steps mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain . Now everything working fine. Thank you :)