# Unsafe attempt to load URL svg

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I am getting an error in Chrome from trying to load an SVG on my local file system:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/Users/Me/Documents/HTML/icons.svg#menu from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Me/Documents/HTML/master.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Here is my HTML:

```
<svg id="icon-menu" viewBox="0 0 70 60">
   <use xlink:href="icons.svg#menu"></use>
</svg>
```

and the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 0 70 70">
  <g
     id="menu">
    <path
       d="m 10,15 50,0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:round;" />
    <path
       d="m 10,30 50,0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:round;" />
    <path
       d="m 10,45 50,0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:round;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I have searched around the internet, but the only solutions I can find are for code already written in JavaScript, but this is not. The HTML above does not work in IE, giving no error, but works without a hitch in Firefox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This page has all the answers, I believe :

https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/

- It just doesn't work on IE unless you use a polyfill.
- Comments down the page describe the issue on Chrome when running locally :

> you can run into some cross-domain issues with this technique when developing locally, if you aren’t developing with a server.

Comment: It seems like Chrome has a real problem with this right now (7/3-16). Seems like it is a browser related bug.

Comment: What's the work around if you're not using CodeKit? I'm using WAMP on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Maybe this topic holds some additional answers : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8449716/3168107.

Comment: Chrome shows this on localhost, but is okay on a faux domain like mydomain.dev

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote on [davidwells.io](http://davidwells.io/blog/fixing-broken-use-tags-from-inline-svg-sprites/) (on this page is also his Javascript solution of the problem):

> I had the same problem when I used external SVG file. I had to change configuration of virtual server and stop automatic redirecting SVG requests from HTTP to HTTPS. Other words: SVG file must be available on both of protocols. Now it working.

Answer (score 0):

use a server such as express.js or apache or nginx to serve the files for you want, preferably an svg sprite that holds all your images you need so you can reference them in the template or front-end like this

```
<svg style="color: red;">
    <use xlink:href="solid.svg#ad"></use>
</svg>
```

and in the back end if you're using express.js in your server.js file like this,

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/sprites'));
```

^ reference a static directory where your svg sprite lives
, that way you can avoid CORS issues. another way is to set the headers using ajax  which another person above me has posted a link to css-tricks.