# Why the SVG icon does not appear in heading?

Tags: html, css, svg

I try to add a SVG icon in the h1 heading element:

```
<h1>
            <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-18">
                <use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#shopping-cart"></use>
            </svg> Buy Full Version Now!
        </h1>
```

But the SVG icon will not appear. THe original URL is https://www.datanumen.com/outlook-repair-order/?nowprocket and I create it in JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/alanccw/871v6jke/3/ to demonstrate the issue. Both will not show the SVG icon.

**Update**

When test in JSFiddle, I get the following error:

```
fiddle.jshell.net/:140 Unsafe attempt to load URL https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg from frame with URL https://fiddle.jshell.net/alanccw/871v6jke/3/show/?editor_console=. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

This issue is discussed in [Unsafe attempt to load URL svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493965/unsafe-attempt-to-load-url-svg/29498134)

But in the original URL, there is no such a problem but the icon still not show.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use `<img>` for this instead?  It can load your SVG.

Comment: @Brad, <img> may not be able to use a symbol in SVG sprite? See my test https://jsfiddle.net/alanccw/871v6jke/6/

Comment: If you are considering images instead, as Brad advises you, please read this [How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Comment: @enxaneta, Thank you. It seems that I need to revise the SVG file to use viewbox to identify different part of the SVG, which is not desired as rather complex.

Comment: Maybe not as complex (unless you don't have any javascript skills) is a modern Web Component to create the SVG for icons: https://iconmeister.github.io

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69475871/16474083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This clearly isn't an issue with your SVG, as you've identified: Your social icons (e.g `.../icons.svg#facebook-f`) are loading without any problems, and they're being loaded from the same SVG sprite.

The problem is your parent div: `cta`. You're hiding everything inside it with the following CSS:

```
single-wporder .hero-page-wporder .cta * {
    display:none;
}
```

And then overriding the style on `cta`'s child elements, using the following:

```
.single-wporder .hero-page-wporder .cta h1, 
.single-wporder .hero-page-wporder .cta h1 svg, 
.single-wporder .hero-page-wporder .cta h1 path {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem is the last line. The `shopping-cart` svg is set to `display:none` inside the sprite, so you just need to target it and all its children to display it.

Update your CSS to this:

```
.single-wporder .hero-page-wporder .cta h1, 
.single-wporder .hero-page-wporder .cta h1 svg, 
.single-wporder .hero-page-wporder .cta h1 svg * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The SVG is now visible, and your CTA elements are still hidden:

[image: Visible shopping cart!]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a style rule is adding `display: none;` to the `<use>` element.

[image]

When I disable this style rule, the SVG appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some CSS is setting `display:none` for the icon in your website.[image]
And in the jsfiddle it doesen't show because this
[image]
Replace your svg code to this in your website. This works perfectly :D.

```
<svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-18">
<use href="/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#shopping-cart" style="display: block;"></use>
</svg>
```

[image: result]