# ajax doesn't work because Brackets keeps changing file path on preview

Tags: jquery, ajax, adobe-brackets

I'm new with programming and I was testing out some simple ajax code with JQuery:

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "AwesomeText.html",
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "Html"    
        })
        .done(test)      
    });
    function test(result){
            $("p").append(result);     
    }
```

It's simple code, I use Brackets for coding and every time I run the code the page opens perfectly fine, the html content is there but the ajax content isn't, so ajax doesn't run for some reason.

This is the file path on chrome's address bar when I run bracket:
http://127.0.0.1:*****/JQurtywAjax.html
I replaced some numbers with stars..

and then when I run the page from its own directory I get the actual file path like this:
file:///C:/Users/comp/Documents/JQurtywAjax.html
and then ajax works here so I know the problem is from Brackets' file path..

how do I fix this ajax problem with brackets and why does it display a different file path?

Comment: [Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP but it's not cross-domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It may be help you.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var _functionURL = "AwesomeText.html";
  var _functionArgs = '{}';
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "" + _functionURL + "",
        data: "" + _functionArgs + "",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            try {
                test(data.d);
            }
            catch (err) { }
        },
        failure: function (response) { }
    });           
});
function test(result){
        $("p").append(result);     
}
```

Comment: this didn't work.. you mean paste it along with previous code or replace it ?

Comment: are you try this code or not ? Because i am using this code in my asp.net project and working fine. i have no problem in this code.