# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/hamma/Desktop/rao.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("rao.txt");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

i want to change the content of div1 with some text or some other webpage without reloading the default page.

I get the following error message in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/hamma/Desktop/rao.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: The console might help?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/hamma/Desktop/rao.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: You can't make AJAX requests to the local file system, you have to setup a webserver, either hosted somewhere or on your local machine.

Comment: above is the error showing in console !

Comment: but it also dosent load any URL . why ?

Comment: Read up on Same-Origin Policy, and Cross-Origin Request Sharing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP but it's not cross-domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain)

Comment: there is window.fetch() now check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44222902/2848256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your console output:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/hamma/Desktop/rao.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

That means that you are trying to run the file without a server i.e. `file:///[...]` and for security reasons you can't run AJAX requests like that.

You need to setup a server and run the page through that to send requests.

**More Help**

If you are using Chrome, try [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787).

**Reading Material**

[Same-Origin-Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: You can't make a request to Google because of the Same Origin Policy, as @JonathonReinhart commented on your question.

Comment: then how can i load a page in a div ? without reloading the default page !

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file "rao.txt" into your project folder. Setup a localserver.
Use wamp/xamp for setting localserver. Access the file like
`http://localhost/project_folder/path_to_rao.txt`