# put my data json in other file and call it into my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hello I am using AngularJS I am developing a simple application, I have some data in my json like :

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.cities = [{
        name: "city A",
        elements: [{
          id: 'c01',
          name: 'name1',
          price: 15,
          qte: 10
        }, {
          id: 'c02',
          name: 'name2',
          price: 18,
          qte: 11
        }, {
          id: 'c03',
          name: 'name3',
          price: 11,
          qte: 14
        }],
        subsities: [{
          name: "sub A1",
          elements: [{
            id: 'sub01',
            name: 'nameSub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 14
          }, {
            id: 'sub02',
            name: 'nameSub2',
            price: 8,
            qte: 13
          }, {
            id: 'sub03',
            name: 'nameSub3',
            price: 1,
            qte: 14
          }]
        }, {
          name: "sub A2",
          elements: [{
            id: 'ssub01',
            name: 'nameSsub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 7
          }, {
            id: 'ssub02',
            name: 'nameSsub2',
            price: 8,
            qte: 1
          }, {
            id: 'ssub03',
            name: 'nameSsub3',
            price: 4,
            qte: 19
          }]
        }, {
          name: "sub A3",
          elements: [{
            id: 'sssub01',
            name: 'nameSssub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 11
          }, {
            id: 'sssub02',
            name: 'nameSssub2',
            price: 2,
            qte: 15
          }, {
            id: 'sssub03',
            name: 'nameSssub3',
            price: 1,
            qte: 15
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        name: "city B",
        elements: [{
          id: 'cc01',
          name: 'name11',
          price: 10,
          qte: 11
        }, {
          id: 'cc02',
          name: 'name22',
          price: 14,
          qte: 19
        }, {
          id: 'cc03',
          name: 'name33',
          price: 11,
          qte: 18
        }]
      }, {
        name: "city C",
        elements: [{
          id: 'ccc01',
          name: 'name111',
          price: 19,
          qte: 12
        }, {
          id: 'ccc02',
          name: 'name222',
          price: 18,
          qte: 17
        }, {
          id: 'ccc03',
          name: 'name333',
          price: 10,
          qte: 5
        }]
      }];
      $scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
        if (itemSelected && itemSelected.elements) {
          $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
        }
      }

    });
```

In order to make a clean code and for a good practice, I need to put data in other json file and call it like :

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.cities = /*call my json here please how can do that*/;
      $scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
        if (itemSelected && itemSelected.elements) {
          $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
        }
      }

    });
```

Please anybody could help me.

**UPDATE**

After your answers I applied them but it didn't work with me , please take a look at what I did :

I installed a server web (xampp) and put all my files on the server

I changed my script like :

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/controllers/data.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.cities = response.data;
  });
  $scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
    if (itemSelected && itemSelected.elements) {
        $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
    }
  }
 }]);
```

and this is my data **data.json**

```
{
"data":[{
        "name": "city A",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "c01",
          "name": "name1",
          "price": "15",
          "qte": "10"
        }, {
          "id": "c02",
          "name": "name2',
          "price": "18,
          "qte": "11"
        }, {
          "id": "c03",
          "name": "name3",
          "price": "11",
          "qte": "14"
        }],
        "subsities": [{
          "name": "sub A1",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "sub01",
            "name": "nameSub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
          }, {
            "id": "sub02",
            "name": "nameSub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "13"
          }, {
            "id": "sub03",
            "name": "nameSub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "sub A2",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "ssub01",
            "name": "nameSsub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "7"
          }, {
            "id": "ssub02",
            "name": "nameSsub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "1"
          }, {
            "id": "ssub03",
            "name": "nameSsub3",
            "price": "4",
            "qte": "19"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "sub A3",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "sssub01",
            "name": "nameSssub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "11"
          }, {
            "id": "sssub02",
            "name": "nameSssub2",
            "price": "2",
            "qte": "15"
          }, {
            "id": "sssub03",
            "name": "nameSssub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "15"
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "city B",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "cc01",
          "name": "name11",
          "price": "10",
          "qte": "11"
        }, {
          "id": "cc02",
          "name": "name22",
          "price": "14",
          "qte": "19"
        }, {
          "id": "cc03",
          "name": "name33",
          "price": "11",
          "qte": "18"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "city C",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "ccc01",
          "name": "name111",
          "price": "19",
          "qte": "12"
        }, {
          "id": "ccc02",
          "name": "name222",
          "price": "18",
          "qte": "17"
        }, {
          "id": "ccc03",
          "name": "name333",
          "price": "10",
          "qte": "5"
        }]
      }];
}
```

but it still couldn't load data

Comment: Store it at server and make http call to fetch it.

Comment: @HarryLim please see my question again I had updated

Comment: what's the error message in browser console for the failed http call ?

Comment: @HarryLim there is no error in my console

Comment: Try adding error handling to monitor the error, 

    $http.get('js/controllers/data.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.cities = response.data;
    }, function(error) { console.log(error); });

Comment: @HarryLim Finally it works thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to inject `$http` service to fetch data from an external source, in your case it is just a JSON file.

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('link to json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.cities = response.data;
  });
  $scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
    if (itemSelected && itemSelected.elements) {
        $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
    }
  }
 }]);
```

Comment: @Abderrahim what is the error you are seeing in the console?  make sure you have the right path of the JSON file in the $http.get()

Comment: yeah I check my console this is the error  XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/web/web/carbu_new/carbu/carbu/js/controllers/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Anyhelp please

Comment: @Abderrahim  I believe you are using google chrome which prevents cross origin requests. Try it on a different browser, it should work.  To make it work in google chrome,see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain

Comment: I use the firefox and internet explorer I had the same probleme

Comment: @Abderrahim are you using a web server?

Comment: NO I have no web server

Comment: @Abderrahim that's the problem , you got to use webserver for http requests.

Comment: I installed a server web and I put all my files on the server but it doesn't work with me

Comment: @Abderrahim  what do you see in the console.log ? any errors

Comment: @Abderrahim glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ajax to fetch the file:

```
$http.get('file.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.cities = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to inject the $http service into your controller, and fire a get request to the json file in your file directory.

Your controller would then look like this:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.cities;
    $scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
        if (itemSelected && itemSelected.elements) {
            $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
        }
    }

    function getCities() {
        $http.get('/data/cities.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.cities = response.data;
        });
    }

}]);
```

This is assuming your json file is named cities.json and is in the location of data/cities.json

Hope this helps.

For more info on best practice, you can refer to John Papa's styleguide @ github:

[Styleguide by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Comment: where '['  of  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) is closed ?

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to close the array apparently!

Comment: But yeah, as mentioned in the other answer you need to use a webserver. you can install one through npm by typing "npm install http-server" and when done, type "http-server -o". After this you simply go the url specified in the console.

Comment: I installed a server web and I put all my files on the server but it doesn't work with me