# Open a website when the node is clicked in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, cytoscape.js, qtip

I am trying to make the network nodes interactive using qtip. This code works with a hard coded network but doesn't work when a network file loads up (JSON format). This is the link to the network file [AKT1.cyjs][1]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <style>
    body { 
         font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
         }
    #cy {
                    margin: auto;
                    border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    top: 20%;
                    overflow: auto !important;
                    border-radius: 0.25em;
                    position: absolute;
                    margin:4px;
                    background:#000;                
    }
    </style>
                  <script>
                  $(function() { 
                $.get( 'AKT1.cyjs', function( data ) {
                 $('#cy').cytoscape({

               style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
                  .selector('node')
                  .css({
                  'content': 'data(name)',
                  'text-valign': 'bottom',
                  'color': 'white',
                  'font-size': 10,
                      'background-color': 'Green'
              })
                  .selector('edge')
                  .css({
                  'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                  'line-color': 'Green',
                  'curve-style':'haystack',
                  'haystack-radius': 0,
                  'width':'data(Ratio)'
              })
                  .selector(':selected')
                  .css({
                  'background-color': 'black',
                      'line-color': 'black',
                      'target-arrow-color': 'black',
                      'source-arrow-color': 'black'
              })
                  .selector('.faded')
                  .css({
                  'opacity': 0.25,
                      'text-opacity': 0
              }),
              elements : JSON.parse(data),



          })
      })


      cy.on('tap', 'node', function(){
      try { 
        window.open( this.data('href') );
      } catch(e){ 
        window.location.href = this.data('href'); 
      } 
    })
      });

            </script>   



  [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzPzj3CcWJQiS3JScFpJMi04ZTQ/view?usp=sharing
```

This is the code that works

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>

        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
          <title>Linkout example</title>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
          </head>
            <style>

    body { 
    font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
     }



    #cy3 {
                    margin: auto;
                    border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    top: 30%;
                    overflow: auto !important;
                    border-radius: 0.25em;
                    position: absolute;
                    left:20%;
                    margin:4px;
                    background:#000;





         }
     </style>


     <script>
     $(function(){ // on dom ready

        var cy3 = cytoscape({
      container: $('#cy3')[0],



      boxSelectionEnabled: false,
      autounselectify: true,

                  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
                      .selector('node')
                      .css({
                      'content': 'data(name)',
                          'text-valign': 'bottom',
                          'color': 'white',
                          'font-size': 10,
                          'background-color': 'data(faveColor)'

                  })
                      .selector('edge')
                      .css({
                      'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                      'line-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                      'curve-style':'haystack',
                      'haystack-radius': 0,
                      'width':'data(Ratio)'
                  })
                      .selector(':selected')
                      .css({
                      'background-color': 'black',
                          'target-arrow-color': 'black',
                          'source-arrow-color': 'black'
                  })
                      .selector('.faded')
                      .css({
                      'opacity': 1,
                          'text-opacity': 0
                  }),
                  elements : {
                      nodes: [  
                            {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '415',
                                  'name' : 'ACTR3',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '414',
                                  'name' : 'CFL1',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '413',
                                  'name' : 'EIF4A1',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '412',
                                  'name' : 'HMGB1',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '411',
                                  'name' : 'HMGB1P1',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '410',
                                  'name' : 'HSP90AB2P',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '409',
                                  'name' : 'HSPB1',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '408',
                                  'name' : 'P4HB',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '407',
                                  'name' : 'TRIM72',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '402',
                                  'name' : 'CASP9',
                                  faveColor: 'white',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '401',
                                  'name' : 'HPRT1',
                                  faveColor: '#B00000',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '400',
                                  'name' : 'AKAP12',
                                  faveColor: '#B00000',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                              },  {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '398',
                                  'name' : 'RNPEP',
                                  faveColor: '#B00000',
                                  href: 'http://js.cytoscape.org'
                                }
                                } ],


                            edges : [ {

                                data : {
                                  'id' : '424',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '415',
                                faveColor: 'green',
                                Ratio: 1.683

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '423',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '414',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  Ratio: 2

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '422',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '413',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  Ratio: 2

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '421',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '412',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  Ratio: 2

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '420',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '411',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  Ratio: 2

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '419',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '410',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  Ratio: 2

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '418',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '409',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  Ratio: 2

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '417',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '408',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  Ratio:1.2

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '416',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '407',
                                  faveColor: 'green',
                                  Ratio: 1.2

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '406',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '401',
                                  faveColor: '#B00000',
                                  Ratio:2.12
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '405',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '400',
                                  faveColor: '#B00000',
                                  Ratio:1.843
                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '404',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '402',
                                  faveColor: 'white',
                                  Ratio:1

                                }
                              }, {
                                data : {
                                  'id' : '403',
                                  'source' : '402',
                                  'target' : '398',
                                  faveColor: '#B00000',
                                  Ratio: 1.49959
                                }

                          } ]

                          },



          });

       cy3.on('tap', 'node', function(){
        try { // your browser may block popups
        window.open( this.data('href') );
      } catch(e){ // fall back on url change
        window.location.href = this.data('href'); 
      } 
    });

    }); // on dom ready


      </script>
      <body>
      <div id="cy3"></div>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: did you check that the content of href data is correctly parsed to a valid url? maybe the issue is in the link itself, rather than in cytoscape.

Answer (score 0):

//You can try using the param 'evt' in the function to access the 'href' data tag.

`cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  var node = evt.cyTarget;
  console.log( 'tapped ' + node.href() );
});`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work :( It's weird how the code works when the network file is hardcoded into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is because of permissions. Put an eyey on [Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP but it's not cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain/14490982#14490982) when someone try to load a .txt file