# How do I display a xml in html using FireFox?

Tags: html, xml

I have to display a XML data in a table in a HTML file.

I try turning off all my extensions on FireFox but I still get a blank screen.

## Employees Details

```
<script>
        var client;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            client = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        client.open('GET', 'employees.xml', false);

        client.onreadystatechange = function() { // will run when the file loads
            // get the response XML
            var xmlDoc = client.responseXML;

            // get the list of user
            var user = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user");

            // get the container where you want to embed the table
            var container = document.getElementById("container");

            var tableString = "<table border='1'>"; // Make a table and put the element data inside it
            for (i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
                tableString += "<tr><td>";
                tableString += user[i].getElementsByTagName("Firstname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                tableString +="</td><td>";
                tableString += user[i].getElementsByTagName("Phone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                tableString += "</td></tr>";
            }
            tableString += "</table>";

            // append the table to the container
            container.innerHTML = tableString;
        }

        client.send();

    </script>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding ="UTF-16"?>
    <user_information>
       <user id="1">
          <Firstname> Bobby </Firstname>
          <Lastname>Drake</Lastname>
          <major>Criminal Justice</major>
          <location>Illinois</location>
          <Phone>(923)949-2302</Phone>
       </user>

       <user>
          <Firstname>Scott</Firstname>
          <Lastname>Summers</Lastname>
          <major> </major>
          <location> California </location>
          <Phone>(395)984-7284</Phone>
       </user>

       <user>
          <Firstname>Jean</Firstname>
          <Lastname>Grey</Lastname>
          <major> </major>
          <location>New York</location>
          <Phone>(843)759-6943</Phone>
       </user>

       <user>
          <Firstname>Kevin</Firstname>
          <Lastname>Sydney</Lastname>
          <major> </major>
          <location>New York</location>
          <Phone>(571)-089-4568</Phone>
       </user>

            <user>
              <Firstname>Suzanne</Firstname>
              <Lastname>Chan</Lastname>
              <major> </major>
              <location>Illinois</location>
              <Phone>(685)-583-2849</Phone>
           </user>

</user_information>
```

I get a blank screen when I open the html in FireFox. I don't know if it is my code or something on my computer. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access these files using file:/// or from a local directory which is causing CORS policy violation and your request is blocked.

You can either use a web-server to deploy the resource and access it. Or check related thread comment which can help you to run Chrome with expected CORS policy.

[Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP but it's not cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain/14490982#14490982)

Comment: So basically I have to create a php to access the xml data?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can create a simple html and xml and deploy it on any webserver.

Comment: Which webserver would be the best to use?

Comment: In this case any webserver would be fine. You can go with Jetty or apache.