# Allure report html is not loading json data

Tags: java, allure

I run tests using Java and collect the results with Allure. As a result folder `allure-results` generated with banch of json files. I can see the report if I use
`allure serve allure-results`.
However, I want to generate html that I can view any time later. So I do it by `allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report`. As a result folder with html file is generated. However, when I open this file the data is not loaded. Please see the attachment below.[image: Allure report]
In console I get CORS policy errors. The example is below.

```
Acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/jgitlin/Documents/proj/CommServ_E2E_Automation/build/allure-results/widgets/summary.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
```

Is there a problem in the way I generate the report or is there a way to see the html properly?

Comment: I think your browser considers it a cross-origin request and blocks it due to the CORS policy

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use any web server of your choice to serve the Allure report, for example Python's built-in HTTP is ok let me explain it to you

first of all open a terminal or command prompt and navigate to the directory where the `Allure report` is generated

then, start Python HTTP server like this (it will start the server on port 9001, but you can use any other port number you like!):

```
python -m http.server 9001
```

at the end, open your browser and go to `http://localhost:9001/allure-report` to view the Allure report!

with this method,you are bypassing the `CORS policy` and allowing the browser to load the necessary resources properly

good luck !

Comment: I prefer this way to view the report as it does not require Allure to be running on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use allure commandline to see actual report;

> allure open allure-report

Answer (score 0):

The error caused by the CORS policy is mainly because cross origin requests are not allowed. To resolve this issue in Google Chrome, you can enable it by adding the "--allow-file-access-from-files" option when running the browser.

You can refer to this:
[Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP but it's not cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain)